# Cómo puedo ordenar secuencialmente una tabla en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos a la comunidad.

Estoy queriendo realizar un orden secuencial en una tabla temporal que tengo en SQL Server, a continuación muestro la tabla:

[image: Tabla]

Esta es mi tabla; las primeras filas que están coloreadas de rojo, verde y azul respectivamente, son las que representan al último nivel en un árbol de contabilidad. Lo que requiero básicamente es que por cada último nivel de este árbol se liste todos los registros que tengan ese mismo número; después que venga el siguiente nivel (14112) y se listen todos los registros que tengan ese código.

Básicamente la tabla quedaría similar a esta:

[image: resultadotabla]

He intentado consultas con `JOIN`, pero no me resultan para nada:

```sql
SELECT 
FROM #tablaTemp TP1 JOIN #tablaTemp TP2 ON TP1.DocIdentidad = TP2.DocIdentidad
WHERE [...]
```

Espero puedan apoyarme. Saludos.

Comment: Sería bueno que agregues un script que contenga la definición de la tabla y la inserción de datos para poder replicar tu ambiente y tratar de ayudarte a encontrar la solución.

Comment: que no es simplemente ordenar codcuenta como una cadena, en lugar de como un numero???????

Comment: Pasa que esto es una pequeña parte de un stored procedure grande, y colocar todo en un script que hace uso de otras tablas aparte, es muy grande. Trataré de colocar un script para la inserción de datos de esta tabla temporal.

Comment: @gbianchi Es lo curioso, eso no resulta; además si resultara, la impresión de la tabla vendría justamente como no requiero. Vendría algo como 14,141, 142,143 14112... y lo que requiero es algo como 14,141,14112,14112,142,143...

Comment: si ordenas como cadena, deberia ordenarse exactamente como vos queres... 14112 esta antes que 142 como cadena.... probaste ordenarlo como cadena?

Comment: si tu orden no es estandar, no hay otra que hacer un proceso que ordene como vos queres... los sistemas saben ordenar de menor a mayor y viceversa... pero no magicamente...

Comment: Como te estan comentando, vas a tener que "ayudarte" con una columna auxiliar que orden como necesitas. Mirando la columna *CodCuenta* tienes que convertirla en un formato comun para ordenar "alfabeticamente" y eso puedes hace conctatenando ceros y que la columna a ordenar quede con la misma cantidad de caracteres. Asi podras ordenarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa como te comentan es que te ayudes con una columna auxiliar para ordenar, y en base a tus comentarios necesitas que esta columna que es numerica ordenarla alfabaticamente (pero sin el orden del numero sino como comienza la cadena). Entonces para esto deberias tener esta columna auxilar con la misma cantidad de caracteres... asi al ordenar quedara como necesitas.

Dale una mirada a este ejemplo online para que pruebes la idea
https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2019/b780f2af87fdd11ff356093c5a0eefe8/

y dejo por aqui el scripts

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Numeros(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    NumeroParaOrdenar INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Numeros(NumeroParaOrdenar)
VALUES (14), (14112), (141), (142),( 143), (14113), (14112)
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Numeros
ORDER BY NumeroParaOrdenar 
GO


SELECT *,   
    NumeroFormateado2 = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NumeroParaOrdenar) + REPLICATE('0', 10), 10)
FROM dbo.Numeros
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), NumeroParaOrdenar) + REPLICATE('0', 10), 10)
GO
```

La salida quedará asi

```
    +====+===================+===================+
| Id | NumeroParaOrdenar | NumeroFormateado2 |
+====+===================+===================+
| 1  | 14                | 1400000000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 3  | 141               | 1410000000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 2  | 14112             | 1411200000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 7  | 14112             | 1411200000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 6  | 14113             | 1411300000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 4  | 142               | 1420000000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| 5  | 143               | 1430000000        |
+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Esta fue la solución, muchísimas gracias.